# File `dashrule.sty' not found (error message)

Tags: packages, texstudio, texmaker, dashrule

While my latex project (including multiple `.tex` file as different chapters) is complied using Overleaf website (LualaTex) without error, however when I try to compile it using `Texmaker` and `TeXstudio`, I get the following error:

> File `dashrule.sty' not found. \usepackage

**PS.** The reason that I can no longer use Overleaf site for this project is that the compile speed of Overleaf has been (intentionally) reduced in free version membership, so that the large projects always get compile timeout error. Otherwise, with Overleaf (LualaTex) the same latex project previously was being compiled without error.

What is the process of fixing this error with `TeXstudio` or `Texmaker`?

I found the following link, how to install `dashrule.sty` ? [Directory macros/latex/contrib/dashrule](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule?lang=en)

**As a maybe easier solution: Is there an alternative to Overleaf without getting compile timeout error?**

Comment: texmaker and texstudio are just the editors, you need to install the package into miktex or texlive, whichever you are using. for texlive that might be `sudo tlmgr install dashrule` depending on how you installed tex in the first place.

Comment: @David Carlisle , How to install `dashrul.sty` in `Miktex`? Where the `dashrul.sty` file is found to be downloaded?

Comment: I don't use miktex, normally it installs things automatically but you should be able to select dashrule in its console. otherwise you could do it by hand just get the files from the ctan link you gave, run tex dashrule.ins and it will make dashrule.sty,  but should not need to do that, letting miktex manage it would be better

Comment: MiKTeX install missed packages on the fly. If you for some disable this functionally, use MiKTeX Console, go to "packages and select missed package and than click on `+` symbol above packages window.

Comment: @Zarko It is done. but another step is remained: after compiling with TexStudio, and after clicking on Install, I get the same error.

Comment: You may/should refresh your file name database (in MiKTeX Console/Tasks) and than also Update package database. (at the same place).